# Google maps api V3 uncaught TypeError 'Cannot read prop Fa or x

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am having an issue with google maps api v3. Up until this point a lot of what I could not work out was easily solved with a quick search and with 9 out 10 solutions found on here. 
Unfortunatly I've been unable to find anything on the errors below.

The map was working fine this morning but work I've done since has somehow started producing errors even though it continues to work.
When I zoom in and out there errors below begin to display in the console output.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Fa' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

I've checked and double checked my code. I cannot see where and why this error is produced.
I am new to JS and html but not new to coding.

Could someone have a look at my page and see if there is anything that stands out which would produce these errors?

Here is the link to the page I am working on.
http://scotflash.co.uk/html52014/pages/guestbook/guestbook.html

Comment: This probably isn't the cause of the issue, but it looks like you're using the [deprecated MarkerImage class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#OverlaysOverview). Search for "MarkerImage" on that page, it says it was replaced by Icon in api version 3.10). It's easy to switch (shown on the page I linked to). Since the problem started happening after some recent changes, can you point us to what was changed?

Comment: The change today was reloading the markers onto the map after someone post's a comment. This works fine.

Comment: It looks like you're loading the "experimental" version of the maps API (version 3.13). If that changed recently, it might be the culprit.  Have you tried version 3.12?

Comment: I had no idea about what version I was using. I changed from v=3.exp to v=3.12 but still the issue is there.

Comment: `loadXML`!= `loadXML(d)`

Comment: Hi David could you elaborate on your one line of code please?

Answer (score 1):

There are guestbook-entries with an empty `img`-attribute, the error occurs when you try to create the marker with the empty `img`. You need a fallback for  this case, e.g.:

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        icon: (guestbookData[i][4])?pin:'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png',
        shadow:(guestbookData[i][4])?pinBackground:null,
        id:guestbookData[i][0],
        con:gbID,
        title: "@"+name+" .::. "+guestbookData[i][0]
    });
```